# Stopping condition by comparing rows in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a following code:

```
def detector(my_array):
    cur = my_array[:,0]
    prev = my_array[:,0]
    for row in my_array:
         prev = cur
         cur = row[0]
         if (cur-prev)>1:
             print("found reverse shift!")
```

Input is a numpy array.

Unfortunately, it returns me a ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

But I am comparing single values not arrays. What's wrong with the code?

Maybe you know a better way to achieve mine goal at all?

Exemplary input:

```
np.array([
(1.1, 0.1), (1.5, 0.2), (1.4, 0.3), (2.1, 0.4), (2.2, 0.5), (-1.1, 0.1), (-0.1, 0.2),  (0.5, 0.3), (1.1, 0.4)
])
```

Expected output:
"Found level shift in row 5"

Assume: there is only one level shift.

Then I'll use 5th row to cut everything below as I don't need these data.

Unfortunately, this is part of ETL process and inputs are given to me in a form of numpy array.

Comment: This looks like a misuse of numpy. You're treating arrays as though they were lists. That's not the case; numpy arrays are completely different and support vectorization which generally means you don't have to iterate them at all

Comment: Please give an example input and the expected output

Comment: You are NOT comparing single values. First line of the loop says `prev = cur` and  `cur` is at first an array (it is set to `my_array[:,0]`)

Comment: Good spot! With my_array[0,1] it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Roberto You should really pay attention to the other comments.